# j'ai tombé, je me suis tombé, je suis tombé... What's the difference?

Tags: verbes, conjugaison, verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires

They all sound the same to me. What could be the difference if there is any?

- j'ai tombé,
- je me suis tombé,
- je suis tombé.

Answer (score 8):

The most common use of *tomber* is an [intransitive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intransitive) verb:

- **Je suis tombé** (de la chaise). <sup>1</sup>
- Je suis tombé (par terre).<sup>2</sup>

In [Classical French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_classique) *tomber* was sometimes used in this sense conjugated with *avoir. It is now outdated and considered "bad" French (at least in France), although some people say it, especially young children who can't speak properly yet, but they're always corrected at school (and by parents).

*Tomber* is correctly used with *avoir* as a transitive verb, for instance:

- Il faisait tellement chaud que **j'ai tombé** la veste.<sup>3</sup>

and in some phrases like:

- Il a tombé son adversaire. <sup>4</sup>
- Il a tombé le masque.<sup>5</sup>

I have never heard *je me suis tombé*, although [it seems to be a "mistake"](http://www.lci.fr/livre/ces-treize-autres-grosses-fautes-de-francais-que-vous-commettez-sans-vous-en-apercevoir-1506172.html) some people make, but I have no idea where.

References: [TFL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/tomber), [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3421)

<sup>1</sup>. <sub>I fell off the chair.</sub>
<sup>2</sup>. <sub>I fell on the floor.</sub>
<sup>3</sup>. <sub>It was so hot I slipped off my jacket.</sub> 
<sup>4</sup>.  <sub>He vanquished his opponent.</sub> 
<sup>5</sup>.  <sub>He took off his mask.</sub>

Comment: *Je me suis tombé* would follow for the transitive use, though, wouldn't it? To cause oneself to fall? For whatever little use such an expression might have...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Not sure I get what you mean, we'd never say *je me suis tombé*. *Je me suis laissé  tomber* would be used as for instance: *je me suis laissé tomber par terre* (I let myself fall onto the ground, I dropped).  *Faire tomber* exists as well: *J'ai fait tomber la bouteille et elle s'est casée* (I dropped the bottle).

Comment: I meant that if you can say "J'ai tombé mon adversaire", you could presumably *tomber* yourself as well. But then again, the possibility of an expression doesn't always translate to its actually being said...

Comment: *J'ai tomber mon adversaire* is accepted but not common. I can't imagine anyone using it for yourself. How can you be your own opponent? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'd expect most occurence of *je me suis tombé* to be analogical expansions of the reflexive. *Tomber* is one of the few verbs of change of position that isn't normally used reflexively. (Its synonyms are: *Je me suis planté*, *je me suis vautré*, etc.). I'm genuinely surprised it isn't more common than it is, actually.

Comment: *J'ai tomb**é** * oups....